# No option for creation on office documents in sharepoint libraries

Tags: sharepoint

Please note that I am missing the option for creation on new office documents in sharepoint libraries. I have setup completely new sharepoint server farm (SharePoint Server 2019) with 4 servers (2 WFE + distributed cache and 2 Apps + search) from scratch.

However, after the installation, I have noticed that I do not have options to create new office documents from the sharepoint libraries. I have tested on multiple site collections and the behavior is the same.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zx0zn.png)

As I know, the options for creation on new documents should be visible by default.

Can you please help me to resolve this issue? Is there a setting that needs to be changed so the option for adding new office files became visible or is it really necessary to install an OOS server? If yes, let me know if only one OOS server is enough?

Please note that I do not have Office package installed on the servers I`m testing this from? I am not sure if this is a problem......

Thank you in advance for the support on this!

I have tried to switch from modern to classic view on the library settings, but the option is still missing. I have turn the setting for management of content types to yes, but the issue persist.

Answer (score 0):

Since Office Online Server provides browser-based file viewing and editing services.
So this issue may related to the installation of Office Online Server.

Here are the documentations for your reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeonlineserver/office-online-server-overview

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeonlineserver/plan-office-online-server

[image]